# Building report using standard date time field

Tags: reporting, datetime

I want to build a report where I can leverage the standard created datetime feature.However the createdDate field reflects only the date in the report.I want both date and time to come in the report.Is there a way of utilising the standard date time field, or do I need to create a custom datetime field and add extra logic via trigger/workflow for it.

Answer (score 2):

The reporting engine automatically drops the time portion on the Created Date field. However, there's a quick way to get them to appear. Simply go to the object, create a new formula, type DateTime, with a formula of CreatedDate, and save it. When you use this field in a report, it will include the date and time.